# How to check if a row does not exist in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following setup:

- A table with columns `a`, `b`, `c`.
- An array with a random number of items (i1, i2, i3,... in).
- Table contains rows like

  ```
  1      1    i1
  1      1    i2
  .      .    .
  .      .    .
  .      .    .
  1      1    in
  1      2    i1
  .      .    .
  .      .    .
  .      .    .
  2      1    i1
  2      2    i2
  ```

The thing is that not all records are there. For example row 1 2 i1 might be missing.

What I would like to do, from query (without getting all rows and iterate through them) is to see IF any row is missing (I don't care witch one, only IF one is missing).

This is a very simplified example for a much more complex problem so if I didn't expose it clear, or I forgot to mention anything feel free to ask for details.

A select and process in PHP is acceptable, as long as I don't select everything in table (although I don't see how to do this by processing data without selecting all but felt like it worth mentioning).

Some of you asked for a pattern so...:

Let's simplify some more... let's say column one has an array of possible data that can be found there, same for column 2, and already said it for column 3. All possible combinations between the 3 of then should be found on the table. I need to know if any are missing...

Comment: so you expect to see 6 rows as missing?

Comment: Do you have reference tables with all applicable values for each of a, b and c?

Comment: How would you or the computer know if a row were missing? What data or pattern are you basing a query on?

Comment: @mark Yes, I know their possible values. Only i1, i2, etc are random.

Comment: I edit in question, maybe I can explain more clear.

Comment: That's not what I asked - do you have a separate table for each of a, b and c, that has all of the applicable values for each?

Comment: So the numbers in col `C` must be sequential for all rows where col `a` and `b` are the same? so `1,1,i1` and `1,1,i2` and `1,1,i4` would show that a row is missing? And then `1,2,i1` could be another pattern?

Comment: Yes... but I got an idea from friederike answer... see my comment. Sorry I couldn't explain it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you know he values for column a and b you could try the following:

```
select c, count (*) group by c;
```

this would tell you how many entries for each value are there.

```
i1  3
i2  0
in  3
```

then you could iterate over that result to see whats missing

Comment: Well... not exactly what I was looking for but that count gave the right idea. I know all possible values... make the sum, select all and compare the result. If any are missing the result will differ.

Comment: cool. wasn't sure what exactly you were trying to do. but I'm glad my idea helped. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have a table with this data.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stuff;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | i1   |
|    1 |    1 | i2   |
|    1 |    2 | i2   |
|    1 |    2 | i3   |
|    2 |    1 | i1   |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lets also assume that all possible values for C is in the table. Then we can construct a reference table like this.

```
mysql> SELECT a,b,c FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM stuff) t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c FROM stuff) t2;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | i1   |
|    1 |    2 | i1   |
|    2 |    1 | i1   |
|    1 |    1 | i2   |
|    1 |    2 | i2   |
|    2 |    1 | i2   |
|    1 |    1 | i3   |
|    1 |    2 | i3   |
|    2 |    1 | i3   |
+------+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can then compare the table with actual data and the reference table by joining them together like this and get all missing rows like this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stuff RIGHT JOIN (SELECT a,b,c FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM stuff) t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c FROM stuff) t2) r ON stuff.a = r.a AND stuff.b = r.b AND stuff.c = r.c WHERE stuff.a IS NULL;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL |    1 |    2 | i1   |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |    2 |    1 | i2   |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |    1 |    1 | i3   |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |    2 |    1 | i3   |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The RIGHT JOIN ON a,b,c will match the rows in the reference table r against the actual rows. The missing rows will manifest as NULL on stuff side. Therefore we can get all missing rows by selecting any row with a NULL field in the stuff table.

Edit: You can change the `SELECT * ...` in the last query to `SELECT count(*) ...` and you get the number of missing rows in this case 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple count.  The number of expected rows is the number of distinct elements in A times the number of distinct elements in B times the number of distinct elements in C.

To count the number that are missing, just do arithmetic on the appropriate values:

```
select (cnt - cntA*cntB*cntC) as NumMissingRows
from (select count(distinct a) as cntA,
             count(distinct b) as cntB,
             count(distinct c) as cntC,
             count(*) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

What about such a query, this might not be the best performance but for a one time task this should work.

```
SELECT t1.id,
(
  SELECT t2.id FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1
) as prv
FROM table t1
HAVING id <> prv + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think about doing it this way, which will still work even if there are duplicates in your list of values. This sames doing any looping over the resulting fields (just a single row comes back which will tell you how many unique in your array are not found on the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT 'i1' AS aCol
UNION
SELECT 'i2' AS aCol
UNION
SELECT 'i3' AS aCol
UNION
.......
UNION
SELECT 'in' AS aCol) Sub1
LEFT OUTER JOIN aTable
ON  Sub1.aCol = aTable.c
WHERE aTable.c IS NULL
```

Could also be modified very easily to bring back a list of the items that are not found should that be required in the future.